# How to filter fetched JSON data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, node-fetch

I'm trying to make a simple command that pulls info from imgur, finds the images, and from there randomly decides which photo to show. The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to filter the responses based on certain criteria. Here is the relevant code:

```
  async execute(interaction) {
    const data = await fetch(
      `https://imgur.com/r/${
        subreddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subreddits.length)]
      }/hot.json`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((body) => body.data)

    const filtered = await data.filter(
      (element) => element.animated == "false"
    );
    console.log(filtered);
    const selected = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
    await interaction.reply({
      content: `https://imgur.com/${selected.hash}${selected.ext.replace(
        /\?.*/,
        ""
      )}`,
    });
  }
```

As you can see, I tried filtering the data based on the animated boolean that is present on each JSON element. False means it is not animated, hence it is an image. But the `filtered` value just returns an empty array `[]`. I'm not sure why it's not passing all of the filtered (image) values as json data. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is one of the multiple elements of JSON info that goes into `data`. Imagine this but 20x from different posts:

```
{
    id: 5987473707,
    hash: 'jV66SOE',
    author: 'RushVoidStaff',
    account_id: null,
    account_url: null,
    title: 'Meet these three brothers! Wheels, Judas and Porridge',
    score: 73947,
    size: 1015100,
    views: '111639',
    is_album: false,
    album_cover: null,
    album_cover_width: 0,
    album_cover_height: 0,
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    ext: '.jpg',
    width: 2048,
    height: 1536,
    animated: false,
    looping: false,
    reddit: '/r/kittens/comments/dmtfvc/meet_these_three_brothers_wheels_judas_and/',
    subreddit: 'kittens',
    description: '#kittens #aww',
    create_datetime: '2019-10-25 06:31:29',
    bandwidth: '105.54 GB',
    timestamp: '2019-10-25 06:40:10',
    section: 'kittens',
    nsfw: false,
    prefer_video: false,
    video_source: null,
    video_host: null,
    num_images: 1,
    in_gallery: false,
    favorited: false,
    adConfig: {
      safeFlags: [Array],
      highRiskFlags: [],
      unsafeFlags: [],
      wallUnsafeFlags: [],
      showsAds: true
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why all those await and asyncs? Please post an example of the data too

Comment: please add a ```console.log(data); // output is ....``` after the init of this variable else data could be anything we have no clues

Comment: @mplungjan @Saren I've added an example of the JSON data value that is given to the `data` const.

Comment: @Koto the attribute animated seem to not exist on the exemple of what you gave us, do you want ```filtered``` to be an array of data where animated doesn't exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the JSON is `false`, not `"false"`. Just replace `== "false"` with `=== false`. The loose equals doesn't work on booleans as javascript sees "false" as a non-empty string, which gets converted to true.

Comment: Some reason? Why would be `"false" == false`? A non-empty string is a truthy value, so it can't be `false`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros oh, yes